# .change not reacting as dynamic as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to javascript, I'm using jquery, this is my html with php code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Quantity 1</h1>
    <input id="btn1" type="number" name="cantpag" value="<?php echo $cp; ?>">

    <h1>Quantity 2</h1>
    <input id="btn2" type="number" name="cantreinv" value="<?php echo $cr; ?>">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#btn1',function(){
        alert('works');
    });
});</script>
```

When I change the value of "#btn1", nothing happens immediately, instead, I must press tab or somwhere else to have the alert show up. Is there any way for this to be instant, as in, just adding or removing a number from the input field triggers the alert?

Comment: 'keyup'. 'change' is not typically used on input fields if you want an immediate execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('input','#btn1',function(){
            alert('works');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Quantity 1</h1>
    <input id="btn1" type="number" name="cantpag" value="<?php echo $cp; ?>">

    <h1>Quantity 2</h1>
    <input id="btn2" type="number" name="cantreinv" value="<?php echo $cr; ?>">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The `input` event should work better. The `change` event on certain elements require a `blur` to register.

Comment: Works great,  ill accept answer as soon as it lets me c: